# Uv/Image Editor doesn't edit my texture

Tags: uv-image-editor

I was trying to add a texture to a cube in Cycles render. I added the texture, it showed up, and could render as well. However, there were some faces which I needed to edit. So, I unwrapped the object and went to the *UV/Image Editor*. But when I tried to scale or rotate my map, didn't affect to the texture. I'm using Blender 2.77.

In some projects it works and some it doesn't.

I described the issue in a [video](https://youtu.be/M6gkE0HfyJ4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use "Texture coordinates" -> "Generated". You need to switch it to "UV" for use your UVMap.

[image]

[image]